# How to make spray paint /over spray effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, photoshop-effects

I wanted to know if anyone knows how to make a similar spray paint effect at includes the overspray effect. In the photo, if you look closely you can see around the surrounding letters & numbers that there's an overspray kinda glow added.[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott I’ve tried adding a out glow and setting the blend to dissolve. I kinda get that overspray effect but not the same as the photo.

Answer (score 1):

That image kind of appear to be a print on some sort of metallic substrate where the "glow" is actually a bleed or smear of the ink.

---

In any event, it takes some experimentation to try and mimic. Often one needs to stack things to get to the end result. This is especially true since no single layer can contain more than one "live" outer glow layer style.

This is merely how I started exploring possible replication.....

---

[image]

---

### **Bottom Up** in the Layer stack...

---

Layer 1 is solid white at 100%

Layer 2 is solid black at 50% opacity

---

## E

Solid black layer then run `Filter > Noise > Add Noise` and tick `Monochrome` and add as much noise as you feel is correct.

When done, Invert the layer (`Image > Adjustments > Invert`). Then add a **Color Overlay Layer Style**:

[image]

Then lower the **opacity** of the layer to around 30% and set the **Blend Mode** to `Multiply`. It's a little prominent here, so I'd most likely play with a lower opacity. Or I'd add a layer mask and run `Fibers` on the layer mask to mask some of the noise. But I've closed the file and it's gone now.

This creates the blue noise present in the background.

---

## D

First Text layer. Simple solid blue text with layer style:

The main difference here is a *lighter* blue is used for *this* glow. the other glows all use the same color as the text.

[image]

**Note** the adjustments in the `Quality` area to the **Contour** and **Range**.

---

## C

Another solid blue text layer with a *different* layer style:

[image]

The main difference here is the color is the same as the text color.

Again note the adjustments in the `Quality` area to the Contour and Range options.

---

## B

Another solid blue text layer with yet another *different* layer style:

[image]

In addition to *much* more noise the adjustments in the `Quality` area create more of the outer diffusion overall. This is why Opacity and the `Elements` items are lower in this layer style.

---

## A

Then....

- **Group** the three text layers.
- **Duplicate** the group and convert it to a **Smart Object**.
- On the Smart Object Layer run `Filter > Gaussian Blur` to add a slight blur to everything.

[image]

---

Then I went back and **adjusted Layer Opacity** for the three original text layers to compensate for the smart object being present:

- **B** I left at 100% opacity
- **C** I set to 20% opacity
- **D** I set to 10% opacity

---

While it's *not* a "perfect" match, it's getting close. From here it merely takes more adjustments and refinement as you see fit.

The primary areas I would focus on to adjust more would be those `Quality` area adjustments in the layer styles. Those will alter the drop off and size of the various glows.

[image]

Comment: .. or.. it's *overprinted* on a metal substrate `:)`